# Listview filter search in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, search

I was wondering how to make the search function works according to the index of my `ListView`? So for instance if I input a **`z`** according to my case, I should not display anything in the `List`.
I have also updated and posted the function `_getTicketDeatils()` here.

```
  var userDetails = {};
  var i;
  List returnTicketDetails = [] ;
 
  body: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Container(
            color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            child: new Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: new Card(
                child: new ListTile(
                  leading: new Icon(Icons.search),
                  title: new TextField(
                    controller: controller,
                    decoration: new InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'Search', border: InputBorder.none),
                   // onChanged: onSearchTextChanged,
                  ),
                  trailing: new IconButton(icon: new Icon(Icons.cancel), onPressed: () {
                    controller.clear();
                   // onSearchTextChanged('');
                  },),
                ),
          new Expanded(
            child: userDetails.length != 0 || controller.text.isNotEmpty
                ? new ListView.builder(
               itemCount: userDetails.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                return new Card(
    
                  child: new Column
                    (mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children:
                    <Widget>[
                    new Row(children: <Widget>[
                    new Container(
                    width: 80.0,
                    height: 80.0,
                    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    image: new DecorationImage(
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    image: new NetworkImage(
                    "https:..")
                )
                )),
                    new Text(userDetails[returnTicketDetails[i]["user_id"]]["first_name"]
                    ),),
                  ,),
                    new Text(userDetails[returnTicketDetails[i]["user_id"]]["last_name"]),
                );
                },
            )
                : new ListView.builder(
               itemCount: userDetails.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                return new Card(
                  child: new ListTile(
                    //title: new Text(userDetails[returnTicketDetails[i]["user_id"]]["first_name"]),
                  ),
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                );
    );
      }
 _getTicketDetails() async {
     final response = await http.get(
         "https..", headers: {
       HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION: access_token
     });
      returnTicketDetails = json.decode(response.body);
     for ( i = 0; i < (returnTicketDetails?.length ?? 0); i++) {
       final ticketresponse = await http.get(
           "https...", headers: {
         HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION:
         access_token
       });
       userDetails[returnTicketDetails[i]["user_id"]] =
           json.decode(ticketresponse.body);
   }
   }
```

[image: This is how my interface looks like right now]

Answer (score 113, accepted):

I've replaced hardcoded model input with getting data from URL as you needed.

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() => runApp(new MaterialApp(
  home: new HomePage(),
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
));

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => new _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  TextEditingController controller = new TextEditingController();

  // Get json result and convert it to model. Then add
  Future<Null> getUserDetails() async {
    final response = await http.get(url);
    final responseJson = json.decode(response.body);

    setState(() {
      for (Map user in responseJson) {
        _userDetails.add(UserDetails.fromJson(user));
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    getUserDetails();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Home'),
        elevation: 0.0,
      ),
      body: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Container(
            color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            child: new Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: new Card(
                child: new ListTile(
                  leading: new Icon(Icons.search),
                  title: new TextField(
                    controller: controller,
                    decoration: new InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'Search', border: InputBorder.none),
                    onChanged: onSearchTextChanged,
                  ),
                  trailing: new IconButton(icon: new Icon(Icons.cancel), onPressed: () {
                    controller.clear();
                    onSearchTextChanged('');
                  },),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          new Expanded(
            child: _searchResult.length != 0 || controller.text.isNotEmpty
                ? new ListView.builder(
              itemCount: _searchResult.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                return new Card(
                  child: new ListTile(
                    leading: new CircleAvatar(backgroundImage: new NetworkImage(_searchResult[i].profileUrl,),),
                    title: new Text(_searchResult[i].firstName + ' ' + _searchResult[i].lastName),
                  ),
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                );
              },
            )
                : new ListView.builder(
              itemCount: _userDetails.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return new Card(
                  child: new ListTile(
                    leading: new CircleAvatar(backgroundImage: new NetworkImage(_userDetails[index].profileUrl,),),
                    title: new Text(_userDetails[index].firstName + ' ' + _userDetails[index].lastName),
                  ),
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  onSearchTextChanged(String text) async {
    _searchResult.clear();
    if (text.isEmpty) {
      setState(() {});
      return;
    }

    _userDetails.forEach((userDetail) {
      if (userDetail.firstName.contains(text) || userDetail.lastName.contains(text))
        _searchResult.add(userDetail);
    });

    setState(() {});
  }
}

List<UserDetails> _searchResult = [];

List<UserDetails> _userDetails = [];

final String url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';
class UserDetails {
  final int id;
  final String firstName, lastName, profileUrl;

  UserDetails({this.id, this.firstName, this.lastName, this.profileUrl = 'https://i.amz.mshcdn.com/3NbrfEiECotKyhcUhgPJHbrL7zM=/950x534/filters:quality(90)/2014%2F06%2F02%2Fc0%2Fzuckheadsho.a33d0.jpg'});

  factory UserDetails.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return new UserDetails(
      id: json['id'],
      firstName: json['name'],
      lastName: json['username'],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I have updated the post with the outcome obtained, however the search does not work as I did not assign string in the same way as you did on your example, do you mind to have a look at it please? Thank you again

Comment: Can you post the userdetails list so that it would be helpful to find the issue.

Comment: Since I won't be able to access the URL can you please give me a sample data for the two variables. Even a single data is enough for me.

Comment: Sure. 
print(userDetails) => {first_name: Test, last_name: Account, profile_image: tempURL}} .
print(returnTicketDetails) => user_id: 513549601, event_id: 843678542, code: TKHRDSJ,

Comment: @HeyabRedda I've edited my answer based on your needs. Check it out and remind me if you need to change anything in my answer or if you don't understand any of it.

Comment: Much appreciated for your effort, however I wanted to clarify that the card gets created dynamically since I send API request, hence the List userdetails cannot really be hardcoded as you did. @Vinoth Kuma

Comment: Take a loot at my new answer.

Comment: I just fixed it! Apparently I missed out an initState. Thank you though!

Comment: When I start a search the keyboard pop up and the list view scrolls up. How to avoid to have the list scroll up ?

Comment: You can use 'resizeToAvoidBottomPadding' property of Scaffold like 'resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,'

Comment: Thanks @Vinoth Kumar. You should write 1 whole tutorial on this, Yours is the best explanation. Helped a lot.

Comment: @VinothKumar Thanks for referring to `Expanded` Widget... That Widget saved my day. `;D`

Comment: In the first search itself I found this code. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 16):

I'm learning Flutter and was looking for a searchable list which @Vinoth Kumar example does perfectly.

I've split the code into different files and reduced the HomePage body into several methods to make it more maintainable/readable for myself and I figured it would be worth sharing.

**`main.dart`**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'homepage.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MaterialApp(
      home: new HomePage(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    ));
```

**`homepage.dart`**

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'userDetails.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  HomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => new _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  List<UserDetails> _searchResult = [];
  List<UserDetails> _userDetails = [];
  TextEditingController controller = new TextEditingController();

  // Get json result and convert it to model. Then add
  Future<Null> getUserDetails() async {
    final response = await http.get(url);
    final responseJson = json.decode(response.body);

    setState(() {
      for (Map user in responseJson) {
        _userDetails.add(UserDetails.fromJson(user));
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    getUserDetails();
  }

  Widget _buildUsersList() {
    return new ListView.builder(
      itemCount: _userDetails.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return new Card(
          child: new ListTile(
            leading: new CircleAvatar(
              backgroundImage: new NetworkImage(
                _userDetails[index].profileUrl,
              ),
            ),
            title: new Text(_userDetails[index].firstName +
                ' ' +
                _userDetails[index].lastName),
          ),
          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildSearchResults() {
    return new ListView.builder(
      itemCount: _searchResult.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, i) {
        return new Card(
          child: new ListTile(
            leading: new CircleAvatar(
              backgroundImage: new NetworkImage(
                _searchResult[i].profileUrl,
              ),
            ),
            title: new Text(
                _searchResult[i].firstName + ' ' +_searchResult[i].lastName),
          ),
          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildSearchBox() {
    return new Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: new Card(
        child: new ListTile(
          leading: new Icon(Icons.search),
          title: new TextField(
            controller: controller,
            decoration: new InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'Search', border: InputBorder.none),
            onChanged: onSearchTextChanged,
          ),
          trailing: new IconButton(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.cancel),
            onPressed: () {
              controller.clear();
              onSearchTextChanged('');
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBody() {
    return new Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        new Container(
            color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor, child: _buildSearchBox()),
        new Expanded(
            child: _searchResult.length != 0 || controller.text.isNotEmpty
                ? _buildSearchResults()
                : _buildUsersList()),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Home'),
        elevation: 0.0,
      ),
      body: _buildBody(),
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: true,
    );
  }

  onSearchTextChanged(String text) async {
    _searchResult.clear();
    if (text.isEmpty) {
      setState(() {});
      return;
    }

    _userDetails.forEach((userDetail) {
      if (userDetail.firstName.contains(text) ||
          userDetail.lastName.contains(text)) _searchResult.add(userDetail);
    });

    setState(() {});
  }
}
```

**`userDetails.dart`**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final String url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';
class UserDetails {
  final int id;
  final String firstName, lastName, profileUrl;

  UserDetails({this.id, this.firstName, this.lastName, this.profileUrl = 'https://i.amz.mshcdn.com/3NbrfEiECotKyhcUhgPJHbrL7zM=/950x534/filters:quality(90)/2014%2F06%2F02%2Fc0%2Fzuckheadsho.a33d0.jpg'});

  factory UserDetails.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return new UserDetails(
      id: json['id'],
      firstName: json['name'],
      lastName: json['username'],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the complete working code, works perfectly.  Changed this to have a non sensitive search (seems to work!):

 `_userDetails.forEach((userDetail) {
      if (userDetail.firstName.toUpperCase().contains(text.toUpperCase()) ||
          userDetail.lastName.toUpperCase().contains(text.toUpperCase())) _searchResult.add(userDetail);
    });`

Answer (score 11):

#### Use `SearchDelegate` (Null Safe):

[image]

---

#### Full code:

```dart
class SearchPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SearchPageState createState() => _SearchPageState();
}

class _SearchPageState extends State<SearchPage> {
  String? _result;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Search')),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(_result ?? '', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                var result = await showSearch<String>(
                  context: context,
                  delegate: CustomDelegate(),
                );
                setState(() => _result = result);
              },
              child: Text('Search'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomDelegate extends SearchDelegate<String> {
  List<String> data = nouns.take(100).toList();

  @override
  List<Widget> buildActions(BuildContext context) => [IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.clear), onPressed: () => query = '')];

  @override
  Widget buildLeading(BuildContext context) => IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.chevron_left), onPressed: () => close(context, ''));

  @override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) => Container();

  @override
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
    var listToShow;
    if (query.isNotEmpty)
      listToShow = data.where((e) => e.contains(query) && e.startsWith(query)).toList();
    else
      listToShow = data;

    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: listToShow.length,
      itemBuilder: (_, i) {
        var noun = listToShow[i];
        return ListTile(
          title: Text(noun),
          onTap: () => close(context, noun),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Undefined 'nouns' name error.

Comment: @Johan I was using [`english_words`](https://pub.dev/packages/english_words) package which has `nouns`.

Answer (score 8):

In Flutter, we have to manage with a custom filter widget and we have to compare tow different objects lists. Such as

```
if (country.name.toLowerCase().contains(searchQuery) ||
          country.name.contains(searchQuery)) {
        filteredRecored.add(country);
      }
```

I found example [here](https://www.developerlibs.com/2018/11/flutter-listview-items-custom-filter.html)

Comment: I found "" .toLowerCase() "" to be very important. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

With reference to **Vinoth Kumar**'s answer, it's good to note that `.contains()` is **case-sensitive**. So, to exhaust all matches, you could transform the strings to lowercase:

```
_userDetails.forEach((userDetail) {
    if (userDetail.firstName.toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase()) || userDetail.lastName.toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase()))
      _searchResult.add(userDetail);
 });
```

Works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 2):

Sometime rebuilding whole screen might not be desirable with `setState((){})`

for this situation you can wrap searchables with `ValuelistenableBuilder` widget.

check this;

```
 Widget searchableUsersWidget() {
    List<Map> users = [
      {'name': 'James', 'tel': '9010'},
      {'name': 'Michael', 'tel': '9011'},
      {'name': 'Jane', 'tel': '9013'},
     
    ];
    ValueNotifier<List<Map>> filtered = ValueNotifier<List<Map>>([]);
    TextEditingController searchController = TextEditingController();
    FocusNode searchFocus = FocusNode();
    bool searching = false;
    return ValueListenableBuilder<List>(
        valueListenable: filtered,
        builder: (context, value, _) {
          return Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: shared.primaryBackgroundColor(),
              borderRadius:  BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                      topRight: Radius.circular(20)),
              boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                        color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5),
                        spreadRadius: 4,
                        blurRadius: 6,
                        offset: Offset(0, 3), // changes position of shadow
                      ),
                    ],
            ),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                  child: Card(
                    child: new ListTile(
                      leading: new Icon(Icons.search),
                      title: new TextField(
                        controller: searchController,
                        decoration: new InputDecoration(
                            hintText: 'Search', border: InputBorder.none),
                        onChanged: (text) {
                          if (text.length > 0) {
                            searching = true;
                            filtered.value = [];
                            users.forEach((user) {
                              if (user['name']
                                      .toString()
                                      .toLowerCase()
                                      .contains(text.toLowerCase()) ||
                                  user['tel'].toString().contains(text)) {
                                filtered.value.add(user);
                              }
                            });
                          } else {
                            searching = false;
                            filtered.value = [];
                          }
                        },
                      ),
                      trailing: new IconButton(
                        icon: new Icon(Icons.cancel),
                        onPressed: () {
                          searchController.clear();
                          searching = false;
                          filtered.value = [];
                          if (searchFocus.hasFocus) searchFocus.unfocus();
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: searching
                          ? filtered.value.length
                          : users.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        final item = searching
                            ? filtered.value[index]
                            : users[index];
                        return ListTile(
                          leading: Avatar(
                            imageUrl: '',
                            color: Colors.amber,
                          ),
                          title: Text(item['name']),
                          subtitle: Text(item['tel']),
                          onTap: () {},
                        );
                      }),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another method to filter the list

```
_searchResult = _userDetails.where(
                    (userDetail) => (userDetail.firstName.contains(text) || userDetail.lastName.contains(text))
                );
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use build in class SearchDelegate

Answer (score 1):

```
           List<Product_Data> product_Data_list=<Product_Data>[];
      List<Product_Data> product_Data_list_all=<Product_Data>[];
 /*  search using productCode code and productName name*/
 

 SearchProduct(String search_text) {
    search_text = search_text.toLowerCase();
    List<Product_Data> allNonbeatStoreList_new = <Product_Data>[];
    print("sarjeet search1  $search_text");
    print("sarjeet search lenth  ${product_Data_list_all!.length}");
    // for(StoreList storeList in product_Data_list_all!){
    for (int i = 0; i < product_Data_list_all!.length; i++) {
      Product_Data storeList = product_Data_list_all![i];
      String storeName = storeList.productName!.toLowerCase();
      String storeCode = storeList.productCode!.toLowerCase();
      print("store code  $storeCode   ${storeCode.contains(search_text)}");
      if (storeName.contains(search_text) || storeCode.contains(search_text)) {
        print("sarjeet search2  $storeCode");

        allNonbeatStoreList_new.add(storeList);
      }
    }

    setState(() {
      print("sarjeet search2 Update");

      product_Data_list = allNonbeatStoreList_new;
    });
    if (search_text.isEmpty) {
      setState(() {
        product_Data_list = product_Data_list_all;
      });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

**In Flutter: - ListView filter using Search**

```
class _RecipeScreenState extends State<RecipeScreen> {
  List<Result>? recipes;
  List<Result>? search_recipes;

  var isLoaded = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    //fetch data from API
    getData();
  }

  getData() async {
    var response = await RemoteServices().postRequest();
    if (response != null) {
      debugPrint("Response = " + response.result.length.toString());
      recipes = response.result;
      search_recipes = response.result;
      setState(() {
        isLoaded = true;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      drawer: NavigationDrawerWidget(),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Recipe"),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.help_outline),
            tooltip: 'Setting Icon',
            onPressed: () {},
          ), //IconButton
        ],
        //<Widget>[]
        backgroundColor: green_color,
        elevation: 5.0,
        systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle.light,
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Card(
            elevation: 2,
            child: TextField(
              cursorColor: black_color,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
              style: edittextStyle,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: "Search",
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(color: grey_color),
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                  prefixIcon: Icon(
                    Icons.search,
                    color: grey_color,
                  )),
              onChanged: searchRecipes,
            ),
          ),
          if (recipes != null) ...{
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: recipes!.length,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Card(
                        elevation: 3,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
                          child: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
                                child: Text(
                                  recipes![index].title,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 18,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Image.network(
                                recipes![index].image,
                                width: double.infinity,
                                height: 220,
                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ));
                  }),
            ),
          } else ...{
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 200),
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            )
          },
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void searchRecipes(String value) async {
    List<Result>? recipe_result = [];
    if (value.isEmpty) {
      setState(() {
        recipes = search_recipes;
      });
      return;
    }
    recipes = search_recipes;
    for (var i = 0; i < recipes!.length; i++) {
      if(recipes![i].title.toLowerCase().contains(value.toLowerCase())){
        recipe_result.add(recipes![i]);
      }
    }
    setState(() {
      recipes = recipe_result;
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an optimized and secure example

[image] [image]

- ***Search Restaurants based on name, Rating, and km***

  ```
        import 'package:advocate/utils/imports.dart';

        class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
          const HomeScreen({super.key});

          @override
          State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
        }

        class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
          final TextEditingController _searchController = TextEditingController();

          final List _restaurantsData = [
            ["Loyal Fire", "5", "10"],
            ["Momento", "4", "12"],
            ["Zesty", "4.5", "2"],
            ["Pizzahut", "3", "5"],
          ];

          final List _searchResultData = [];

          void getMatch() {
            String value = _searchController.text;
            for (var item in _restaurantsData) {
              if (item[0].contains(value) || item[1] == value || item[2] == value && !_searchResultData.contains
           (item)) {
                setState(() => _searchResultData.add(item));
              }
              if (value == "") setState(() => _searchResultData.clear());
            }
          }

          void clearSearch() {
            setState(() {
              _searchController.text = "";
              _searchResultData.clear();
            });
          }

          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("Top Restaurant Near You ")),
              body: Column(
                children: [
                  ListTile(
                    title: TextField(
                      controller: _searchController,
                      onChanged: (value) => getMatch(),
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        hintText: "  Search restaurant by Name, Km, Rating ",
                        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey)),
                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1.0)),
                      ),
                    ),
                    trailing: IconButton(icon: const Icon(Icons.clear), onPressed: () => clearSearch()),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: _searchResultData.isEmpty
                        ? RestaurantListView(listData: _restaurantsData)
                        : RestaurantListView(listData: _searchResultData),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          }
        }

        class RestaurantListView extends StatelessWidget {
          const RestaurantListView({super.key, required this.listData});

          final List listData;

          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: listData.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(listData[index][0]),
                    leading: SizedBox(
                      width: 50,
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          const Icon(Icons.star),
                          Text(listData[index][1]),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    trailing: Text("${listData[index][2]} Km"),
                  );
                });
          }
        }
  ```

Answer (score -1):

add this in your `pub.yaml` file: `flutter_slidable:^0.5.4`

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'produit_bloc.dart';
    import 'produit_service.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_slidable/flutter_slidable.dart';
    
    class CRUDListView extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _CRUDListViewState createState() => _CRUDListViewState();
    }
    
    class _CRUDListViewState extends State<CRUDListView> {
      List<Produit> _produits;
      List<Produit> _searchProduct;
      TextEditingController controller = new TextEditingController();
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        _produits = [];
        _searchProduct = [];
        _getEmployees();
      }
    
      _getEmployees() {
        ProduitService.getProduits().then((produits) {
          setState(() {
            _produits = produits;
          });
          print("Length ${produits.length} ");
        });
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
          appBar: new AppBar(
            title: new Text('SEARCH ON LISTVIEW'),
            elevation: 0.0,
          ),
          body: new Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              new Container(
                color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                child: new Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: new Card(
                    child: new ListTile(
                      leading: new Icon(Icons.search),
                      title: new TextField(
                        controller: controller,
                        decoration: new InputDecoration(
                            hintText: 'Search', border: InputBorder.none),
                        onChanged: onSearchTextChanged,
                      ),
                      trailing: new IconButton(
                        icon: new Icon(Icons.cancel),
                        onPressed: () {
                          controller.clear();
                          onSearchTextChanged('');
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              new Expanded(
                child: _searchProduct.length != 0 || controller.text.isNotEmpty
                    ? new ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: _searchProduct.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                          return new Slidable(
                            actionPane: SlidableDrawerActionPane(),
                            actionExtentRatio: 0.25,
                            child: Container(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              child: ListTile(
                                leading: Text(('${_searchProduct[i].id}')),
                                title: Text(('${_searchProduct[i].article}')),
                                trailing: Text(('${_searchProduct[i].prixu}')),
                              ),
                            ),
                            actions: <Widget>[
                              IconSlideAction(
                                caption: 'Archive',
                                color: Colors.blue,
                                icon: Icons.archive,
                                onTap: () {
                                  print('archive');
                                },
                              ),
                              IconSlideAction(
                                caption: 'Share',
                                color: Colors.indigo,
                                icon: Icons.share,
                                onTap: () {
                                  print('share');
                                },
                              ),
                            ],
                            secondaryActions: <Widget>[
                              IconSlideAction(
                                caption: 'More',
                                color: Colors.black45,
                                icon: Icons.more_horiz,
                                onTap: () {
                                  print('more');
                                },
                              ),
                              IconSlideAction(
                                caption: 'Delete',
                                color: Colors.red,
                                icon: Icons.delete,
                                onTap: () {
                                  print('delete');
                                },
                              ),
                            ],
                          );
                        },
                      )
                    : new ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: _produits.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return new Slidable(
                            actionPane: SlidableDrawerActionPane(),
                            actionExtentRatio: 0.25,
                            child: Container(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              child: ListTile(
                                leading: Text(('${_produits[index].id}')),
                                title: Text(('${_produits[index].article}')),
                                trailing: Text(('${_produits[index].prixu}')),
                              ),
                            ),
                            actions: <Widget>[
                              IconSlideAction(
                                caption: 'Archive',
                                color: Colors.blue,
                                icon: Icons.archive,
                                onTap: () {
                                  print('archive');
                                },
                              ),
                              IconSlideAction(
                                caption: 'Share',
                                color: Colors.indigo,
                                icon: Icons.share,
                                onTap: () {
                                  print('share');
                                },
                              ),
                            ],
                            secondaryActions: <Widget>[
                              IconSlideAction(
                                caption: 'More',
                                color: Colors.black45,
                                icon: Icons.more_horiz,
                                onTap: () {
                                  print('more');
                                },
                              ),
                              IconSlideAction(
                                caption: 'Delete',
                                color: Colors.red,
                                icon: Icons.delete,
                                onTap: () {
                                  print('delete');
                                },
                              ),
                            ],
                          );
                        },
                      ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    
      onSearchTextChanged(String text) async {
        _searchProduct.clear();
        if (text.isEmpty) {
          setState(() {});
          return;
        }
    
        _produits.forEach((produit) {
          if (produit.article.contains(text) || produit.prixu.contains(text))
            _searchProduct.add(produit);
        });
    
        setState(() {});
      }
    }
```