# Flutter: I have a problem to each element of this collection in iteration order of JSON data

Tags: json, flutter, dynamic, foreach

I have a problem to each element of this collection in iteration order of JSON data.

This is what I want (example):

[image]

This is I have:
[image]

I am trying to follow this example (https://stackoverflow.com/a/50569613/12908336) and am facing such a problem.

Now my  data is List < dynamic>.
[image]

```
class MaintenanceInfo {
  final String serial,...;

  MaintenanceInfo({this.serial,...});

  factory MaintenanceInfo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return new MaintenanceInfo(
      serial: json['serial'],
      .... );}}
```

some sample JSON data :

```
{"ResultText": "Success","ResultStatus": 0,"data": [{"serial": "-1",....},{"serial": "-1",....}]}
```

Comment: I have not understand your error yet :(
Kindly paste the error

Comment: @MuhammadTameemRafay I want to change List data; (List < dynamic> data) to List<MaintenanceInfo> data;  **type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<MaintenanceInfo>' of 'function result'**

Comment: what happens if you declare the List data; as "List <MaintenanceInfo> data;" and import the MaintenanceInfo file at the top??

Comment: @MuhammadTameemRafay  data is null. ;(

Comment: than insert the data first in variable then loop it :)