# How do I add search option in this app's Appbar?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to add search option in this app. Adding search bar in Appbar then create filter/search in Listview.

That means,In my Appbar I will give a input in searchbar if it matches with any item from the list, it shows the item. The data of the list comes from a CSV document. So I found it complex.

How should I do it? I have attached my code part by part in the post.

Thanks in advance.

[first part of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28RgD.png)

[middle part of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYllL.png)

[last part of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJGLl.png)

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com). While including links might be helpful, questions should be self-contained, so please add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) showing what you tried. Regarding the question. Also, add a brief description of your search efforts, as suggested in [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: check it, hope it help [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50567295/listview-filter-search-in-flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50567295/listview-filter-search-in-flutter)

Answer (score 0):

You can add the search bar as `title` in your appBar.

[image]

```
 title: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8),
                child: Container(
                    height: 40,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 15),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Color.fromARGB(70, 255, 255, 255),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15.0))),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      textInputAction: TextInputAction.search,
                      onFieldSubmitted: (value) async {},
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 15),
                      cursorColor: Colors.white,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                      controller: _textFieldController,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          suffixIcon: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment:
                                MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween, // added line
                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, // added line
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
                                  child: InkWell(
                                      onTap: () async {},
                                      child: Icon(Icons.search,
                                          color: Colors.white))),
                            ],
                          ),
                          isDense: true,
                          border: InputBorder.none,
                          hintText: "Search",
                          contentPadding:
                              EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 10.0),
                          hintStyle:
                              TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 15)),
                    ))),
```

Comment: actually I wanted, I will give a input in searchbar if it matches with any item from the list, it shows the item. The data of the list comes from a CSV document. So I found it complex.

Could you please give me solution for it? I have attached my code part by part in the post.

( I am sorry, I can't ask the question properly)