# how to increase the size of the window with the search result in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a page code written in an android studio. On this page, I display a list of objects, as well as a widget to search for these objects. When I clicked on the search widget,my list of objects is shrinking, and it is almost invisible (it is at the top). Can this be fixed somehow so that it can be seen on the whole page ??

```html
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app_seals/model/post/form_unseals.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app_seals/model/post/form_seals.dart';
import  'package:flutter_app_seals/model/setting/globalvar.dart' as global;
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:convert';

void main() => runApp(JsonParseObjectSts_UN());
class JsonParseObjectSts_UN extends StatefulWidget {

  JsonParseObjectSts_UN() : super();

  @override
  _JsonParseObjectsState createState() => _JsonParseObjectsState();
}

class _JsonParseObjectsState extends State <StatefulWidget> {
  List<UserDetails> _searchResult = [];
  List<UserDetails> _userDetails = [];
  TextEditingController controller = new TextEditingController();




  final String url = global.urlVar  ;
  // Get json result and convert it to model. Then add
  Future<Null> getUserDetails() async {


    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.badCertificateCallback = ((X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true);


    final request = await client
        .getUrl(Uri.parse(url))
        .timeout(Duration(seconds: 5));

    HttpClientResponse response = await request.close();


    var responseBody = await response.transform(utf8.decoder).join();


    final responseJson = json.decode(responseBody);

    setState(() {
      for (Map user in responseJson) {
        _userDetails.add(UserDetails.fromJson(user));
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    getUserDetails();
  }

  Widget _buildUsersList() {
    return new ListView.builder(
      itemCount: _userDetails.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return new Card(
          color: (_userDetails[index].sealed  == "Так") ? Colors.redAccent : Colors.greenAccent,
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 7),
          child: ListTile(
              title: Text(
                _userDetails[index].name,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
              ),
              subtitle: Text("Запломбований:${_userDetails[index].sealed}"),
              leading: Icon(
                Icons.home_outlined,
                size: 30,
                color: Colors.black87,
              ),
              onTap: () =>
              {
                if ('Так' == _userDetails[index].sealed) {
                  global.nameObj =  _userDetails[index].name,
                  global.sealsNumb = _userDetails[index].seal_number,
                  global.typesOp = 'Так',
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Unseals()),
                  )
                }
                else{
                  {
                    global.nameObj =  _userDetails[index].name,
                    global.typesOp = 'Ні',
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Form_seals()),
                    )
                  }
                }
              }
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildSearchResults() {
    return new ListView.builder(

      itemCount: _searchResult.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, i) {
        return new Card(
          color: (_searchResult[i].sealed  == "Так") ? Colors.redAccent : Colors.greenAccent,
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 7),
          child: ListTile(
              title: Text(
                _searchResult[i].name,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
              ),
              subtitle: Text("Запломбований:${_searchResult[i].sealed}"),
              leading: Icon(
                Icons.home_outlined,
                size: 30,
                color: Colors.black87,
              ),
              onTap: () =>
              {
                if ('Так' == _searchResult[i].sealed) {
                  global.nameObj =  _searchResult[i].name,
                  global.sealsNumb = _searchResult[i].seal_number,
                  global.typesOp = 'Так',
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Unseals()),
                  )
                }
                else{
                  {
                    global.nameObj =  _searchResult[i].name,
                    global.typesOp = 'Ні',
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Form_seals()),
                    )
                  }
                }
              }
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildSearchBox() {

    return new Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(7.0),
      child: new Card(

        child: new ListTile(
          leading: new Icon(Icons.search),
          title: new TextField(
            controller: controller,
            decoration: new InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'Пошук', border: InputBorder.none),
            onChanged: onSearchTextChanged,
          ),
          trailing: new IconButton(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.cancel),
            onPressed: () {
              controller.clear();
              onSearchTextChanged('');
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  Widget _buildBody() {

    return new Scaffold(
      body:Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: [Colors.blue, Colors.white],
              begin: Alignment.topCenter,
              end: Alignment.bottomCenter),
        ),
        child:Column(
          children: <Widget>[
           new Expanded( flex: 1, child: _buildSearchBox()),
            new Expanded(flex:8,
                child: _searchResult.length != 0 || controller.text.isNotEmpty
                    ? _buildSearchResults()
                    : _buildUsersList()),
          ],
        ),

      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        body: _buildBody()
    );
  }

  onSearchTextChanged(String text) async {
    _searchResult.clear();
    if (text.isEmpty) {
      setState(() {});
      return;
    }

    _userDetails.forEach((userDetail) {
      if (userDetail.name.contains(text) ) _searchResult.add(userDetail);
    });

    setState(() {});
  }
}


class UserDetails {

  final String name, seal_number,sealed;



  UserDetails({this.name, this.sealed, this.seal_number});

  factory UserDetails.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return new UserDetails(
      sealed: json['sealed'],
      name: json['name'],
      seal_number: json['seal_number'],
    );
  }
}
```

My page:
[image]

My page with search:
[image]

Comment: Try this package: autocomplete_textfield: ^1.7.3

Comment: @PrabhanshuTiwari thank you, but without this package it can somehow work ??

Comment: You can use showSearch instead. It is a built-in method

Comment: Actually I m not able to run your code that's why I am suggesting packages or you can provide more info

Comment: @PrabhanshuTiwari I will try to give you more information

Comment: @PrabhanshuTiwari I will use this example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50567295/listview-filter-search-in-flutter, but with my api, he does, but he does not do something in me .

Comment: @PrabhanshuTiwari but api takes the data correctly

Answer (score 1):

I have looked at your code several times, I just noticed a small error.

For the results of your searches, you try to display the "List" of searches in a ListView.builder, which is in a column in the parent container does not have a defined height.

Solution: Set a height for the main container and the problem will be solved