# flutter add searchfield to sqlite data

Tags: flutter, dart, search

I am a little new to Flutter and are trying to add a searchfield to output of a piece of script i have from a tutorial.

The data is from a sqlite db and i want to add a searchfield that is looking in the output from the database. Can someone help me a little of where to begin of do you know an example of this kind of question?

code where i want to add it is:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Joost mag het weten'),
      ),
      body: _isLoading
          ? const Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      )
          : ListView.builder(
        itemCount: _journals.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => Card(
          color: Colors.orange[200],
          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
          child: ListTile(
              leading: Text(_journals[index]['aantal']),
              title: Text(_journals[index]['title']),
              subtitle: Text(_journals[index]['description']),
              trailing: SizedBox(
                width: 100,
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    IconButton(
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.edit),
                      onPressed: () => _showForm(_journals[index]['id']),
                    ),
                    IconButton(
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.delete),
                      onPressed: () =>
                          _deleteItem(_journals[index]['id']),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              )),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () => _showForm(null),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50567295/listview-filter-search-in-flutter answer your question? Here is also a youtube video about filtering listview https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZHdg2kfKmjI

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Listview filter search in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50567295/listview-filter-search-in-flutter)