# Put nested JSON in Flutter List and apply search filter on List

Tags: json, flutter, list, search

I Have Nested JSON List I want to add this list in flutter Widget, I have try it before few days but not found proper solution.

Am sharing with you json Data like below. You can found full json file [here](https://github.com/ravindra6596/search_filter_json/blob/main/search_list.json)

```
[{
        "month": "July",
        "services": [{
                "name": "Opening Balance",
                "amount": 5566.12
            },
            {
                "name": "Property Rates",
                "amount": 0
            }

        ]
    },
    {
        "month": "August",
        "services": [{
                "name": "Waste Disposal",
                "amount": 0
            },
            {
                "name": "Water Basic",
                "amount": 0
            },
            {
                "name": "Water Metered",
                "amount": 0
            },
            {
                "name": "Interest",
                "amount": 81.63
            },

            {
                "name": "Closing Balance",
                "amount": 6145.05
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "month": "September",
        "services": [{
                "name": "Opening Balance",
                "amount": 6145.05
            },
            {
                "name": "Property Rates",
                "amount": 107.4
            }

        ]
    },
    {
        "month": "October",
        "services": [{
                "name": "Opening Balance",
                "amount": 6319.27
            },
            {
                "name": "Property Rates",
                "amount": 107.4
            },
            {
                "name": "Sanitation Basic",
                "amount": 0
            },
            {
                "name": "Waste Disposal",
                "amount": 0
            },
            {
                "name": "Water Basic",
                "amount": 0
            },
            {
                "name": "Water Metered",
                "amount": 33.65
            },
            {
                "name": "Interest",
                "amount": 83.04
            },
            {
                "name": "Journal Credit",
                "amount": 0
            },
            {
                "name": "Total",
                "amount": 224.09
            },
            {
                "name": "Closing Balance",
                "amount": 6543.36
            }
        ]
    }

]
```

I have above string json to dart -> model file [here](https://github.com/ravindra6596/search_filter_json/blob/main/json_model)

Expected Result of all list -> [image]

Expected result after search by month name -> [image]

Result after search-> [image]

Listview Code:

```
   ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: userList.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return   ListTile(
                      title: Text(userList[index]['month']),
                      leading:
                          Text(userList[index]['services'][index]['name']),
                      trailing: Text(userList[index]['services'][index]
                              ['amount']
                          .toString()),
                    );
                  },
                ),
```

Current Result-> [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First iteration is ok, but you have to iterate again for every month in order to display services...

Try something like this:

```
ListView.builder(
  shrinkWrap: true,
  itemCount: userList.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return ListTile(
     title: Text(userList[index]['month']),
     subtitle: ListView.builder(
       shrinkWrap: true,
       itemCount: userList[index]['services'].length,
       itemBuilder: (context, index2) {
         return Row(
           children: [
             Text(userList[index]['services'][index2]['name']),
             Text(userList[index]['services'][index2]['amount']),
           ]
          ),
         );
       },
      ),
```

Regarding the search, you have an example here:
[Listview filter search in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50567295/listview-filter-search-in-flutter)

Anyway depending on the context of your application I'd suggest you to work with objects and not with maps, and to do the search from the provider and not with a stateful widget.

Comment: Pablo Nicolas Oshiro Mondoñedo,I have try your answer its Working Well but what about Search Filter

Comment: I want search filter on it also its nested JSON and its complicated to me

Comment: I have Solved issue regarding Search Filter please see above answer given by me

Answer (score 0):

I have try it Following Way

Create Lists:

```
List<SearchList> userList = [];
List<SearchList> search = [];
```

Search Filter:

```
 void _runFilter(String enteredKeyword) {
    List<SearchList> results = [];
    if (enteredKeyword.isEmpty) {
      // if the search field is empty or only contains white-space, we'll display all users
      results = userList;
    } else {
      results = userList
          .where((user) =>
              user.month!.toLowerCase().contains(enteredKeyword.toLowerCase()))
          .toList();
      // we use the toLowerCase() method to make it case-insensitive
    }
    // Refresh the UI
    setState(() {
      search = results;
    });
  }
```

Widget:

```
Column(
      children: [
        TextField(
          onChanged: (value) {
            _runFilter(value);
          },
          controller: editingController,
          decoration: const InputDecoration(
              labelText: "Search",
              hintText: "Search",
              prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(25.0)))),
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 20,
        ),
        search.isEmpty
            ? TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  fetchData();
                },
                child: const Text('Load'),
              )
            : Expanded(
                child: ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: search.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                        border: Border.all(),
                      ),
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          horizontal: 10, vertical: 5),
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            search[index].month.toString(),
                            style: const TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 18,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(
                            height: 10,
                          ),
                          ListView.builder(
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                            itemCount: search[index].services!.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index2) {
                              return Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                    MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                children: [
                                  Text(search[index]
                                      .services![index2]
                                      .name
                                      .toString()),
                                  Text(search[index]
                                      .services![index2]
                                      .amount
                                      .toString()),
                                ],
                              );
                            },
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
      ],
    ),
```

You Can Found Full Widget Code [here](https://github.com/ravindra6596/search_filter_json/blob/main/search_filter.dart)